# Laravel - SuperAdmin can't see other roles

Tags: laravel, permissions, admin, roles

I added this in my User model:

```
    private $rank;

    public function isSuperAdmin(): bool {

        if ($this->rank >= 3) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function isAdmin(): bool
    {
        if ($this->rank == 2 || $this->isSuperAdmin()) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function isCustomer(): bool {
        if ($this->rank == 1|| ($this->isSuperAdmin() || $this->isAdmin())) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

I have rank '3' which equals the `isSuperAdmin()` function. So when I do the following:

```
if (Auth::user()->isSuperAdmin())
```

This works as expected. However when I, as SuperAdmin, try to do the following:

```
if (Auth::user()->isAdmin())
```

It doesn't work at all, Laravel doesn't display whatever is between `@if(Auth::user()->isAdmin())` in my views when I have the role SuperAdmin. This is the same for all the roles and I don't understand why.. what am I doing wrong?

Ps. I also tried the following in the `isAdmin` function, which also doesn't work:

```
if ($this->rank >= 2 || $this->isSuperAdmin()) {
```

Comment: What does that mean `It doesn't work at all`? What exactly does not work?

Comment: @codedge Laravel doesn't display whatever is between @if(Auth::user()->isAdmin) when I have the role SuperAdmin. This is the same for all the roles.

Comment: What is the output of `dd($this->rank)`?

Comment: I fixed it. Turned out $this->rank was always null because of the private $rank. When I removed that, everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I removed `private $rank` everything worked as expected.